# Как работать с Start-Job в Power Shell?

Tags: powershell

В написанном скрипте:

```
[xml]$inputs = New-Object system.Xml.XmlDocument
$inputs.Load('.\inputs.xml') 

[string]$result = ''
[string]$adresses = ''

foreach ($server in $inputs.SelectNodes('//server'))
{
    $hostname = $server.host                                    #   получаем DNS имя сервера
    Start-Job {                                                 #   стартуем задание
        if (Test-Connection $hostname -Quiet)
        {
            $result += "Ping to " + $hostname + " success`r`n"      #   формируем содержимое файла report.txt
            $port = $server.port
            $sock = new-object System.Net.Sockets.Socket -ArgumentList $([System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily]::InterNetwork),$([System.Net.Sockets.SocketType]::Stream),$([System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType]::Tcp)
                try {
                    $sock.Connect($hostname,$Port) | Out-Null       #   попытка соединения
                    $result += "port " + $port + " connect success`r`n"
                    $result += "`r`n"
                    $sock.Close()
                    }
                catch {
                $result += "port " + $port + " connect fail`r`n"
                $result += "`r`n"
                } 

        }
        else
        {
            $result += "Ping to " + $hostname + " fail`r`n"         #   формируем содержимое файла report.txt
        }
    }                                                           #   конец задания
}
$result += "`r`n"

foreach ($process in $inputs.SelectNodes('//process'))          #   определяет какие процессы запущены
{
    if (Get-Process -Name $process.InnerText -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    {
        $result += "Process " + $process.InnerText + " exists`r`n"
    }
    else
    {
        $result += "Process " + $process.InnerText + " not exists`r`n"
    }
}
$result += "`r`n"

foreach ($service in $inputs.SelectNodes('//service'))
{
    if (Get-service -Name $service.InnerText -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    {  # 
        $Servicestatus = Get-service $service.InnerText | select status, DisplayName      # получение списка служб в Powershell
        $result += "Service " + $service.InnerText + " " + $Servicestatus.status + "`r`n"
    }
    else
    {
        $result += "Service " + $service.InnerText + " " + "not exists`r`n"
    }

}

Start-Sleep -Sec 99                                                 #   задержка чтобы пинги отработали

Out-File -FilePath .\report.txt -InputObject $result -Encoding Default
foreach ($adress in $inputs.SelectNodes('//email'))
{
    $adresses += $adress.InnerText + "; "
}
if ($adresses -ne '')
{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook         #   ошибка если нет Outlook на компе
    $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    $Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)

    $Mail.To = $adresses
    $Computer = Get-WmiObject  -Class win32_ComputerSystem

    $Mail.Subject = "Testing report on "+ $Computer.Name
    $Mail.Body =$result
    $Mail.Send()
}
```

предполагается что в первом цикле foreach будут пинговаться хосты и результаты этих пингов будут заноситься в переменную $result, но этого не происходит. Весь остальной код отрабатывает без проблемм!

Вопрос: подскажите что я в первом цикле foreach делаю не так?